# What dismissal by Sarah is Godolphin referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-favourite

In The *Favourite* (2018), after she ended the friendship with Anne, Sarah met Godolphin:

> Godolphin: Obviously, you have chosen to **keep the particulars of your
>   dismissal from me**. I shall leave a gap in the conversation for you to
>   remedy that. I do not know of women and their feelings, but I know
>   they nurse their hurts like wailing newborns.
>
> Sarah: Godolphin, I feel a surge of desire to see your nose broken.
>   Your point?
>
> Godolphin: A letter. An apology of some sort that facilitates your
>   return.

What dismissal by Sarah is he referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Her [dismissal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dismissal) from the court.

> - an act of officially removing an employee from their job

Or [in a broader sense](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dismissal):

> - The act of ordering or allowing someone to leave.